# Windows repeat last command without arrow keys

Tags: windows, windows-11

Usually you can use the upwards arrow key to get the previous command.

But with a 60% keyboard, there are no arrow keys. How can you navigate powershell without arrow keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the operations to some other keys.

PowerShell uses PSReadLine to process input, which is very similar to Bash's readline/inputrc in terms of behavior – in fact, it has nearly same function bindings that Bash's readline does.

For example, if you wanted to bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to Previous/Next, add the following to your `$Profile` script:

```
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord Ctrl+p -Function PreviousHistory
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord Ctrl+n -Function NextHistory
```

(Note: The chords are case-sensitive, so "-Chord Ctrl+P" would actually bind Ctrl+Shift+P.)

Alternatively, bind those keys to the `HistorySearchBackward`/`..Forward` functions, which work very similarly to the standard up/down but with prefix filtering – e.g., typing `setUp` will jump to the last command starting with "set".

```
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord Ctrl+p -Function HistorySearchBackward
```

Also just like in Bash, there's a built-in binding for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> `ReverseSearchHistory` which provides a full substring search, and is usually better than up-arrowing a hundred times.

Finally, there's <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>?</kbd> `WhatIsKey` to find out what `-Chord` value you need to use for a given keypress.

---

It's also possible to bind keys to custom code (e.g. this PowerShell 5 bugfix for people still using it on Windows 10):

```
# https://github.com/Microsoft/console/issues/282
Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Chord Shift+SpaceBar -ScriptBlock {
    [Microsoft.Powershell.PSConsoleReadLine]::Insert(' ')
}
```

Comment: I've always wondered how people survive _in general_ using keyboards without arrow keys? Don't such keyboards at least have macros like Fn+WASD or Fn+hjkl, or do you just have to use the mouse / backspace over everything?

Comment: quite a few of those are fancy keyboards you can program layers in, so I'd guess spend lots of time setting up a keyboard no one else can use :D

Comment: I usually don't use my arrow keys at all. I've found it to be inefficient. Except for browsing the terminal history (haha). This answer is perfect, thanks a million.